# Fatal error: Class 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth' not found in.. in the sub folder

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I am trying to tweet posts to my twitter account.
Therefore I am trying famous `https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth` script.

My folder structure is:

```
www.mysite.com/twitterbot/
|-- twitteroauth (folder) 
|   |-- Util (folder)
|   |   `-- JsonDecoder.php
|   |-- autoload.php
|   |-- Config.php
|   |-- Consumer.php
|   |-- HmacSha1.php
|   |-- Request.php
|   |-- Response.php
|   |-- SignatureMethod.php
|   |-- Token.php
|   |-- TwitterOAuth.php
|   |-- TwitterOAuthException.php
|   `-- Util.php
`-- index.php
```

And my `index.php`

```
    <?php

        require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";
        use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
        $consumerKey = "myconsumerkey"; // Consumer Key
        $consumerSecret = "mycinsumersecret"; // Consumer Secret
        $accessToken = "myaccesstoken"; // Access Token
        $accessTokenSecret = "my access token secret"; // Access Token Secret
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);
        $statues = $connection->post("statuses/update", array("status" => "I'm posting a tweet!"));

?>
```

When I visit to `www.mysite.com/twitterbot/` is says `**Fatal error**: Class 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth' not found in mysitecom/twitterbot/index.php on line 8`

8th line is `$statues = $connection->post("statuses/update", array("status" => "I'm posting a tweet!"));`

What I am doing wrong?
how can I fix this?

Comment: Where is twitteroauth/autoload.php? I don't see it in your dir structure.

Comment: sorry I missed it in questions. please check my `updated folder structure`

Comment: You might need to put the `twitteroauth` directory inside an `abraham` directory, assuming that this package is using a PSR autoloading scheme.

Then change the include to `require "abraham/twitteroauth/autoload.php";`

See http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: still same. have a look on folder structure : http://postimg.org/delete/w67kd3h12/
and index.php is: http://postimg.org/image/xrmk2j24r/

Comment: Ah! You extracted the src folder. Stick with the original structure found in github. I tried your code and a fresh copy from github and I'm not experiencing your error. The PSR actually defines this requirement

Comment: Yes, you can't change the structure of TwitterOAuth files. `autoload.php` expects to be at the same level as a directory named `src` which contains all the needed PHP files.

Comment: thank you both.. no errors now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your folder structure should really not change from the original like so (disregard the duplicate mysitecom folder)

[image]