# Fatal error: Class 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth' not found

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to tweet posts to my twitter account. I am download the required library files from https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

**I am geting the error**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth'
>   not found in
>   D:\xamp\htdocs\Shasta_Tools\trunk\CEP\Twitter\SampleCode\connect\index.php:12
>   Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   D:\xamp\htdocs\Shasta_Tools\trunk\CEP\Twitter\SampleCode\connect\index.php
>   on line 12

**Folder structure:**

[image]

**Sample Code:**

```
<?php
require "twitteroauth/autoload.php";
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

// Set keys
$consumerKey = 'MyConsumerKey';
$consumerSecret = 'MyConsumerSecret';
$accessToken = 'MyAccessToken';
$accessTokenSecret = 'MyAccessTokenSecret';

// Create object
$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);

// Post Update
$content = $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'Test Tweet'));
?>
```

I already refered
[Fatal error: Class 'Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth' not found in.. in the sub folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33515812/fatal-error-class-abraham-twitteroauth-twitteroauth-not-found-in-in-the-sub)

[Class not found PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28386315/class-not-found-php)

How to resolve this issue.

Please advise!

Comment: I see a `composer.json`, which seems to indicate you're using Composer, which means you shouldn't **be** downloading any files. You should be doing `composer install` or `composer require abraham/twitteroauth`, as shown in the install docs at https://twitteroauth.com/.

Comment: Now I am Donload files and use composer. Problem 1
    - The requested package abraham/twitteroauth No version set (parsed as 1.0.0) is satisfiable by abraham/twitteroauth[No version set (parsed as 1.0.0)] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.

Comment: Show us your `composer.json` contents. There's no version 1.0.0. Try `composer require abraham/twitteroauth ^0.7.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do `composer require abraham/twitteroauth`. This will solve your issue.